# Delete Entry from MySql database Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to delete an entry from a database. I am submitting 'wantid' from a form in my template. I've been searching for hours, but can't seem to make this work. I assume it is something basic that I just don't understand. If someone can look at this and let me know what they see, I would be grateful!

@app.route("/deletewant", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def deletewant():

```
wantid = request.form.get('wantid')
x = WantIt.query.filter_by(wantid=wantid)
db.session.delete(x)
db.session.commit()

return redirect('/wantit')
```

note- WantIt is the table name. wantid is the primary key.

Comment: please show the model as well

Comment: class WantIt(db.Model):

    wantid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    author = db.Column(db.String(120))
    binding = db.Column(db.String(30))
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        
    def __init__(self, name, author, binding):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.binding = binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a method on the Query object to actually return an item from the database.

So instead of this:

```
x = WantIt.query.filter_by(wantid=wantid)
```

Do this:

```
x = WantIt.query.filter_by(wantid=wantid).first()
```

See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars

Comment: Thanks. This got me past that error, I think. Now I'm throwing another one. I'll post a new question.

Comment: I figured the next problem out. Thanks, though!